# Python - Codec Issue with the video file downloaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, codec

I am trying to download a video that has been uploaded in the cloud, and I am using API's to extract the data.

The python script seems to download the file fine, but when I open the video it throws this error:

[image]

I have tried using different options (VLC, Windows Media Player, etc) to play the video but do not have any luck. Can someone please help?

```
if res.status_code == 200:
    body = res.json()
    for meeting in body["meetings"]:
        try:
            password = requests.get(
                f"{root}meetings/{meeting['uuid']}/recordings/settings?access_token={token}").json()["password"]
            url = f"https://api.zoom.us/v2/meetings/{meeting['uuid']}/recordings/settings?access_token={token}"
            res = requests.patch(
                url,
                data=json.dumps({"password": ""}),
                headers=sess_headers)
        except:
            pass

        topic = meeting["topic"]

        try:
            os.makedirs("downloads")
        except:
            pass
        for i, recording in enumerate(meeting["recording_files"]):
            #os.makedirs(topic)
            download_url = recording["download_url"]
            name = recording["recording_start"] + \
                "-" + meeting["topic"]
            ext = recording["file_type"]
            filename = f"{name}.{ext}"
            path = f'./downloads/{filename}'.replace(":", ".")
            res = requests.get(download_url, headers=sess_headers)

            with open(Path(path), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(res.content)
else:
    print(res.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried downloading any of these URLs directly by some downloader? Not by python script. Also unplayable?

Comment: Directly downloading works fine. The JSON response has a link & when I try to open that link in a browser the file auto downloads.

Comment: It could be the case that `requests.get()` function receives some strange `Content-Type` and converts content to some non-binary format.

Comment: can you print the value of res.status_code after doing the last ``requests.get`` request?

Comment: If you have `curl` tool then do next thing - `curl -I https://google.com/` but substitute instead of google url your download url. This command will dump HTTP headers, check what `Content-Type` string is there.

Comment: Also after each `requests.get()` insert next line `res.raise_for_status()`.

Comment: Raise for status mentioned by me above is needed because requests never checks status of each response, if it is 200 or not. This `res.raise_for_status()` throws exception if status was not 200.

Comment: I added  print(res.status_code) to my code after the last requests.get(), and it returned me 200 for every time it goes in loop

Comment: @Karu3103 Have you also tried `curl -I` command that I mentioned above? So that we can see headers of response. Specifically `Content-Type` line is interesting to see.

Comment: @Karu3103 Can you also try to visually compare files contents in some viewer, what is the size difference and content difference of two files - one downloaded by `requests.get()` and another one downloaded manually by downloader.

Comment: @Karu3103 Instead of last requests get try to do `res = requests.get(download_url, headers = {**sess_headers, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})`

Comment: HTTP/2 200
date: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 14:48:34 GMT
content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
content-length: 39074
server: ZOOM

Comment: Also the file sizes were a lot less when they got downloaded as part of the Python script. It was only about 38kb while the actual file size was about 50 mb

Comment: @Karu3103 `Content-Type: text/html` - this is showing definite problem, it means that file is just an HTML file. Try renaming this file to `test.html` and open it in browser, look what it contains.

Comment: 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8' was what I was getting when I tried to view the headers. But how come when I directly open the link the file gets downloaded? Any idea?

Comment: @Karu3103 Some servers respond with status code 200, while still having some errors. Then instead of sending you a video file they send you HTML text with error description contained inside.

Comment: @Karu3103 Try renaming your file downloaded to `test.html` and open it in browser. Look what's inside. There is most definitely a details with error description from server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223038/discussion-between-arty-and-karu3103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem is next:

After doing each `res = requests.get(...)` you need to insert line `res.raise_for_status()`.

This is needed to check that status code was 200.

By default `requests` doesn't throw anything if status code is not 200. Hence your `res.content` may be an invalid response body in case of bad status code.

If you do `res.raise_for_status()` then `requests` will throw error if status code is not 200, thus saving you from possible problems.

But having status code of 200 doesn't definitely mean that there was no error. Some servers respond with HTML containing error description and status code 200.

Another possible problem could be that download url is missing authorization token inside it, then you need to provide it through headers. So instead of last `requests.get(...)` put next code:

```
res = requests.get(download_url, headers = {
    **sess_headers, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
```

Also you need to check what content type resulting response has, so after last `res = response.get(...)`, do next:

```
print('headers:', res.headers)
```

and check what is inside there. Specifically look at field `Content-Type`, it should have some binary type like `application/octet-stream` or `video/mp4`. But definitely not some text format like `application/json` or `text/html`, text format file is definitely not video file. In case if it is `text/html` then try renaming file to `test.html` and open it in browser to see what's there, probably server responded with some error inside this HTML.

Also just visually compare in some viewer content of two files - downloaded by script and downloaded by some downloader (e.g. browser). Maybe there is some obvious problem visible by eye.

Also file size should be quite big for video. If it is like `50KB` then possibly some bad data is inside there.

**UPDATE**:

Finally worked next solution, replacing last `requests.get(...)` with line:

```
res = requests.get(download_url + '?access_token=' + token, headers=sess_headers)
```